# Moving counters on a chessboard

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

$25$ counters, numbered from $1$ to $25,$ are placed on the squares of a $5 \times 5$ chessboard, as shown below.

[image: chessboard]

Mabel wants to move each counter to an adjacent square (horizontally or vertically, but not diagonally), so that as before, each square contains exactly one counter. In how many ways can they do this?

I'm pretty sure we need to use a one-to-one correspondence or the pigeonhole principle, but I don't know how to go about doing it.

Comment: What have you tried?  (Note that this is not a site for "Here's a problem... solve it for me.")

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I would say that "I'm pretty sure we need to use a one-to-one correspondence or the pigeonhole principle, but I don't know how to go about doing it" is sufficient context

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Let's say that we had a $2 \times 2$ board instead.  Then according to what I think the question is asking, the only valid rearrangements would be
$$
\pmatrix{2&1\\4&3}, \ \pmatrix{3&4\\1&2}, \ 
\pmatrix{3&1\\4&2}, \ \pmatrix{2&4\\1&3}.
$$
Are these the kind of rearrangements that we're talking about?

Comment: Also could you explain why you believe we're supposed to use a one-to-one correspondence or the pigeonhole principle?  Is this from a class you're taking? From a textbook?

Comment: Another perspective on the problem is that we're looking for a digraph that is a subgraph of the $5 \times 5$ [grid graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GridGraph.html) for which each node has in degree and out degree one.

Comment: @Lily Potter: This is an active homework problem from an online class.  Please do not discuss homework on outside websites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After doing this operation, the $13$ counters on white tiles will each move to one of the $12$ black tiles. By Pigeonhole, a black tile will be used at least twice. So there are **no** ways to do this procedure.